# how to use variables in code?

Tags: javascript

How can I shorten the code using variables instead of using `document.body.innerHTML` every time ?

```
function smurfa() {    
     document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Katt/g,'Caca'); 
     document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/katt/g,'caca'); 
     document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/morr/g,'prutt');
     document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Morr/g,'Prutt');      
     }
```

I've tried creating variables like:

```
var where=document.body.innerHTML   
var morf= document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Morr/g,'Prutt')   
var results= where + morf;
results;
```

Comment: `location` is a window property. Rename that variable so it doesn't conflict with any of the window properties that have special meaning

Comment: Where is your question????

Comment: This doesn't work :( any suggestions?

function smurfa() {
   var where = document.body.innerHTML  
   var morf = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Katt/g,'Caca') 
   document.body.innerHTML.replace(/katt/g,'caca') 
   document.body.innerHTML.replace(/morr/g,'prutt')
   document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Morr/g,'Prutt')
  var result= where + morf;
  result;
}

Comment: OK, so you've shown what you tried, that's the first stage of a [mcve]. Now you need to tell us what happened when you tried that, and what you wanted to happen. Right now, there's nothing to answer here.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer.
I would like to replace all the occurrences of the words "Katt","katt","Morr" and "morr" to -> "Caca", "caca" etc..
It works if I write it out as stated before:                        
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Katt/g,'Caca');

But the code is pretty long and would like to use variables instead if possible.
Thanks

Comment: Nothing happens when i run the code with variables...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
function smurfa(regex, replace) {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex, replace);
  return smurfa;
}

smurfa(/Katt/g,'Caca')(/katt/g,'caca')(/morr/g,'prutt')(/Morr/g,'Prutt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable to `document.body`, since that's an object and you can update its property. Setting a variable to the property itself won't work; variables are not references to properties, they get the property by value.

```
var b = document.body;
b.innerHTML = b.innerHTML.replace(/Katt/g, 'Caca');
```

You can also chain the substitutions:

```
b.innerHTML = b.innerHTML.replace(/Katt/g, 'Caca').replace(/katt/g, 'caca').replace(/morr/g, 'prutt').replace(/Morr/g, 'Prutt');
```

You can also use a function as a replacement to do all the replacements at once:

```
b.innerHTML = b.innerHTML.replace(/katt|morr/gi, function(match) {
    const replacements = { 'Katt': 'Caca', 'catt': 'caca', 'morr': 'prutt', 'Morr': 'Prutt' };
    return replacements[match];
});
```

BTW, it's generally a bad idea to replace the entire `document.body` like this. It causes the entire DOM to be discarded and replaced by re-parsing its HTML. Any properties or event listeners added to elements will be lost.

Instead, you should write a loop that finds all the text nodes, and replaces their text contents.

Comment: Thanks man it worked!
Great insight, I will try with text nodes also.